# Session expires during Virtual Machine image upload to Bluemix

Tags: file-upload, virtual-machine, session-timeout, ibm-cloud

When I attempt to upload a virtual appliance to Bluemix, my session expires causing the upload to fail. The appliance image is stored on my local machine and I follow the following process, having first logged into Bluemix:

From the Dashboard, I select 'Run Virtual Machines', which opens the 'Create a Virtual Machine' page. Then, I select 'Upload image' in the right-hand frame. I select ISO as the image format, then click the 'Browse' button and select the appliance ISO from my local disk.

Then I click 'Upload' and the upload begins. After a period of time, during the upload, the following message appears:

'Your session has expired, click OK to refresh the page and renew it. You might be asked to login if necessary'.

At this point the upload is terminated.

How do I resolve the issue of my session expiring part-way through the upload? Is there a robust method for uploading virtual machine images to Bluemix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably your iso image is too big to be uploaded using your network speed, the browser session ends before your upload is finished.

I think about two options available for you:

- open two different browser tabs/windows, use the first one to upload your image and use the second one to keep manually your session not expired (simply navigating on bluemix dashboard): not really useful, especially for a very long upload...
- instead of uploading your image from local, you can upload your image from an external URL (the second value on the combo box 'How to upload'

[image: attachment file]

if you downloaded your ISO previously, you can simply use on Bluemix dashboard the same URL used to download it locally; if you have your own image locally only, you should upload it on the web (on a shared hosting for example) and then use the URL pointing to your uploaded ISO to download it to Bluemix

Comment: The first option appears to work around the issue. I can now upload the image. I didn't attempt the second option as the image is only available on my local disk. Thanks.

Comment: In my case, I was migrating my instance from US South to the UK. I simply copy the URL from the "Download Image" link, and pasted it in the dialog that you screenshotted as you suggested. My image then appeared in the list under the "Exisiting" tab

Answer (score 0):

You can use glance CLI (which are a set of python scripts) to upload images. Please refer to http://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/common/cli_install_openstack_command_line_clients.html for installation instructions on the platform of your choice.

You can also check this tutorial which shows step-by-step instructions on  how to install the CLI clients.

https://www.mirantis.com/blog/mirantis-openstack-express-installing-openstack-cli-clients/

Though the UI calls the same from under the covers, you will at least reduce the overhead of the UI.